# responsive layout with html5

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I would like to create a responsive layout using html5 and css3. After reading a bit on the internet I got really confused as where to start. From what I've read there are frameworks that help develop responsive layouts:

- [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/)

This is where the confustion starts:

1. What is the benefit of using these frameworks?
2. Where can I find tutorials that would teach me to go from PSD => HTML5 Responsive layout => and I guess then use the framework.
3. Do I need to use these frameworks?

Comment: You basically need a grid system. Bootstrap offers one, with other usefil stuff. I would suggest looking at the Scaffholding section under bootstrap's documentation

Comment: and basically Responsive = using Media Queries in CSS (i'd suggest googling that too) to change the display of your content in a way that works for different screen sizes

Comment: A responsive layout is more a coding/scripting technique.  I've tried frameworks and some cms systems, and I've found I prefer to start from scratch and maintain full control.

Comment: There is also the [PURE](http://purecss.io/) framework

Comment: The opinions that people give help form a more expert opinion because the more people that can give some knowledge and experience of their own and some may even give websites with proof and explanations on what they did. This question is valid because it is not only helpful for others but it can provide new information that might be found through a simple google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These frameworks have lots of classes generated to set up a grid system really quickly and easily. For example, Bootstrap has a bunch of classes that help set up a fluid grid with each `<div>` or container having a fluid width that could be different compared to its adjacent container.

To go from a PSD to a responsive layout to using a framework is tricky, and a lot of people like to work from mobile layouts and create PSD's for those smaller devices to help them figure out what is the most important content and put that in the top of the page for mobile and more towards the center or with more emphasis on desktop. To move to a responsive layout, it's really all about creating a PSD for pretty much every breakpoint you plan to have, that way you know where everything should go and it makes it a lot easier. Using the responsive layout framework is pretty much a part of the layout design process, because you use the framework for its abilities, so it's important to know what the framework can and can't do that way you don't design something that is impossible.

These frameworks just create lots of nice features that make responsive development a lot easier and simpler for beginners, you may want to just make a sample site with the framework, and then after you could move on to doing it yourself because lots of times you may not use everything the framework offers and taking it out and overriding its classes is a pain. Frameworks get you started and learning and you decide if you are comfortable using them.

Happy coding!

Comment: but to me it seems like all the sites have to follow the same standard and will pretty much look the same or very similar. isn't that the case? And doing it the old way, that is cutting up PSD (like here: http://www.ultimatedesignertoolkit.com/tutorials/psd-html-easy-ultimate-css-framework/) does that still apply to those frameworks? I'm just confused on PSD to grid system HTML part.

Comment: Going from psd to HTML doesn't need to be an exact replica, it's more of just getting an idea together and then knowing what the site should look like.

Comment: Most sites are different, go to apple.com, then to google..com, then to adobe.com. They each have a different navigation structure in a different place and work differently and their content is in different places.

Answer (score 1):

1. Some of the work is done for you already. (If they do things in a way you don't want, then that isn't a benefit, of course).
2. Questions asking for tutorial recommendations are off-topic for Stackoverflow
3. No.